# Why would GCE instance group manager recreate a VM?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

The recreated VM instance got assigned a new external IP and caused other issues(e.g. couldn't connect to remote servers because the new IP was not being whitelisted...)

Why would the instance group manager recreate a VM instance? Is there any way to prevent this recreation?

Comment: By default, instances in the group will be placed in the default network and randomly assigned IP addresses from the regional range.  you can restrict the IP range of the group by creating a custom mode VPC network and subnet that uses a smaller IP range, then specifying this subnet in the instance template. This can simplify the creation of firewall rules. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/

Answer (score 0):

There are two kind of instance group:

**The Managed instance groups**:

Which uses an [instance template](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates/) to create a group of identical instances. and you control a managed instance group as a single entity the managed instance group can [automatically scale](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/) the number of instances in the group. If an instance in the group stops, crashes, or is deleted by an action other than the instance groups commands, the managed instance group automatically recreates the instance so it can resume its processing tasks.
Managed instance groups work with [load balancing services](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/) to distribute traffic to all of the instances in the group.

If your Instance template allow HTTP(S) traffic, then any Instance created will have an External IP, You can set the Autoscaling  to **"off"**, If you don't need Instances to be created , but you can set the number of instances that you want to be managed.

Note: the right usage for Instance group is to manage the workload and the load balancer distribute the traffic equally to all instances.

**The Unmanaged instance groups**

Unmanaged instance groups are groups of dissimilar instances that you can arbitrarily add and remove from the group. Unmanaged instance groups do not offer autoscaling, rolling update support, or the use of instance templates.